# Not equals eu un Join LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

tengo dos listas de objetos, una es de objetos tipo **Product** con las propiedades **codigo**, **nombre**, **descripcion** y **precio**.
La otra es de objetos de tipo **ProductS2** que hereda de **Product** pero implementa alguna propiedad más como **codigo2**.

Con un `Join` extraigo todos los objetos que existen en ambas listas:

```
List<Product> LArticlesWC =  Ccon.ObjecteWC.Product.GetAll();
List<Cproduct200> LArticles200 =  Funcions.S200ToProducte(parametresConnexio);
var dup = (from wcProduct in LArticlesWC
            join s200product in LArticles200
            on wcProduct.codigo.Trim() equals s200product.codigo2.Trim()
            select s200product).ToList();
```

Pero me gustaría saber como podría hacer un "`not equals`" que me retornara todos los elementos de **LArticles200** que no están en **LArticlesWC**, teniendo en cuenta que no contiene el mismo tipo de objetos.
He visto que la forma de hacerlo seria con `Except`, pero no puedo hacerlo al no ser del mismo tipo.
Me podéis echar un cable por favor.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma seria utilizar la funcion `Contains` el cual valida que exista el contenido en la coleccion dada y a esta funcion le aplicarias la negacion .

Ejemplo:

```
LArticles200.Where(x => ! LArticlesWC.Select(y => y.codigo.Trim()).Contains(x.codigo2.Trim()));
```

otra opcion seria con la funcion `Any`

```
LArticles200.Where(x =>LArticlesWC.Select(y => y.codigo.Trim()).Any(y=>y!=x.codigo2.Trim()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer una consulta directa sobre  `LArticles200` y seleccionar los elementos que no existan en `LArticlesWC`:

```
var dup = (from s200product in LArticles200
            where 
            
            // Seleccionar registros de LArticles200
            // que no están en LArticlesWC
    
            !LArticlesWC.Select( la => la.Codigo.Trim())
            .Contains(s200product.Codigo2.Trim())
    
            select s200product
            )
            .ToList();
```